# Javascript: Call a function after specific time period

Tags: javascript, function, timer

In JavaScript, How can I call a function after a specific time interval?

Here is my function I want to run:

```
function FetchData() {
}
```

Comment: `setTimeout()`? `setInterval()`?

Answer (score 210, accepted):

You can use [JavaScript Timing Events](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) to call function after certain interval of time:

This shows the alert box every 3 seconds:

```
setInterval(function(){alert("Hello")},3000);
```

You can use two method of time event in javascript.i.e.

1. `setInterval()`: executes a function, over and over again, at
   specified time intervals
2. `setTimeout()` : executes a function, once, after waiting a
   specified number of milliseconds

Comment: Be mindful that the sample does NOT give the most exact answer to the question (it answer the question "how can I call a function _every_ specific interval, not _after_ a specific interval

Answer (score 58):

Execute function `FetchData()` **once** after 1000 milliseconds:

```
setTimeout( function() { FetchData(); }, 1000);
```

Execute function `FetchData()` **repeatedly** every 1000 milliseconds:

```
setInterval( FetchData, 1000);
```

Comment: I guess in case of 'setInterval()' the round brackets for the function name i.e. 'FetchData' should not be present because it triggers the function only once. setInterval(FetchData,1000) seems more valid. I  tested it in chrome.

Comment: This is incorrect. In the setTimeout the FetchData() will run straight away. You need to wrap it in a function like so : setTimeout(function() { FetchData(); }, 1000);

Answer (score 9):

ECMAScript 6 introduced arrow functions so now the setTimeout() or setInterval() don't have to look like this:

```
setTimeout(function() { FetchData(); }, 1000)
```

Instead, you can use annonymous arrow function which looks cleaner, and less confusing:

```
setTimeout(() => {FetchData();}, 1000)
```

Comment: You know what's even cleaner? `setTimeout(FetchData, 1000)`

Comment: Well, if you use any argument inside the FetchData() the script will run right away. so you need to wrap it in the function brackets like I mentioned above.

Comment: OP never mentioned any arguments and the function he posted doesn't have any parameters either.

Comment: Does not matter, when you learn new things you don't want to sacrafice utility for more clarity, correct?

Answer (score 8):

sounds like you're looking for [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=window.setInterval). It's as easy as this:

```
function FetchData() {
  // do something
}
setInterval(FetchData, 60000);
```

if you only want to call something once, theres [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout).

Answer (score 3):

#### Timeout:

```
setTimeout(() => {
   console.log('Hello Timeout!')
}, 3000);
```

#### Interval:

```
setInterval(() => {
   console.log('Hello Interval!')
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout(func, 5000);

-- it will call the function named func() after the time specified. 
here, 5000 milli seconds , i.e) after 5 seconds