# How to fade multiple background colors after few seconds?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I want to know how can I change the background color after couple of seconds in css?

For example I want 3 colors: blue, red, green. After each 3 seconds the background color is changing.

Does anyone has any idea?

This is my code. But I can change only 2 colors and is not looping

```
p {
    display: inline;
    animation: background-fade 3s forwards;
    -webkit-animation: background-fade 3s forwards;
    -moz-animation: background-fade 3s forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes background-fade {
    100% {
        background:#c92884;
    }
}
```

JSFidlle 
    http://jsfiddle.net/326mJ/7/

Comment: What is you current code? please supply a jsfiddle

Comment: have a look on my edit

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/326mJ/8/

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23458640/how-to-have-css3-animation-to-loop-forever

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kztyasg1/)**

```
body{

animation: background-fade 10s infinite;    
}

@keyframes background-fade {
    0% {
        background:red;
    }
    50% {
        background:blue;
    }
    100% {
        background:green;
    }
}
```

You need to use `infinite` instead of `forwards` for looping

Comment: Small improvement: http://jsfiddle.net/kztyasg1/1/

Comment: Yup, Thanks for the edit :)