# Shine effect automatically with css

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, effects

I'm trying to do this shine effect operate automatically (without a: hover), every 5 seconds.

http://jsfiddle.net/AntonTrollback/nqQc7/

```
.icon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -110%;
  left: -210%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.13);
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right, 
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.13) 0%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.13) 77%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 92%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 100%
  );
}

.icon:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  top: -30%;
  left: -30%;
  transition-property: left, top, opacity;
  transition-duration: 0.7s, 0.7s, 0.15s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}
```

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23458640/how-to-have-css3-animation-to-loop-forever

Comment: Can you state what's going wrong? Many people might be unwilling to click on the link, which presumably shows the problem, because it could go anywhere.

Comment: I'm trying make the shine effect work automatically every X seconds, but now this effect only work with :hover. @GrahamAsher

Comment: Use animation instead of transition.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can create CSS animation like this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nqQc7/512/)**

```
 @keyframes shine{
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    top: -30%;
    left: -30%;
    transition-property: left, top, opacity;
    transition-duration: 0.7s, 0.7s, 0.15s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: -30%;
    left: -30%;
    transition-property: left, top, opacity;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Anderson  are you sure, i just got it that you want it to run every 5 sec but this is not it. I will figure it out soon.

Comment: Do you know how can i disable that transition?

Comment: Yes. I'm sure this help me.

Comment: Ok i think i got it. This one shine like you wanted every 5 sec http://jsfiddle.net/nqQc7/512/

Comment: True. It is even better, actually.

Comment: Is it possible to do this over an entire table row?

Comment: Very cool. Thanks! In case it helps other people: I applied the shine animation to a form and, because of other styling rules, the "shine" layer (the ":after") stayed on top of the form for a while. It was not a problem style-wise, but it prevented users from selecting the form inputs. To solve it, I just added this rule to the :after selector: "pointer-events: none;"