# CSS animation Start Over from beginning

Tags: html, css

I need some help if someone can help

I have many lines with fadeout animation with different seconds and I need the first line start over after the last line animation ends

Comment: Hi thanks for posting! As per Stack Overflow guidelines you should post the code of your attempt here, preferrably in a code fiddle ("<>" icon).

Comment: You can set the number of iterations or infinite for starting over the animation infinite times, as in: `animation-iteration-count: number|infinite`

Comment: This can be done purely with CSS but it relies on knowing how many animations at what durations. So we need to see your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `#Path_1468{animation: fadeOut 0.1s;}
#Path_1469{animation: fadeOut .2s;}
#Path_1470{animation: fadeOut .3s;}
#Path_1471{animation: fadeOut .4s;}
#Path_1472{animation: fadeOut .5s;}
#Path_1473{animation: fadeOut .6s;}
#Path_1474{animation: fadeOut .7s;}
#Path_1475{animation: fadeOut .8s;}
#Path_1476{animation: fadeOut .9s;}
#Path_1477{animation: fadeOut 1s;}
#Path_1478{animation: fadeOut 1.1s;}
#Path_1479{animation: fadeOut 1.2s;}
#Path_1480{animation: fadeOut 1.3s;}
#Path_1481{animation: fadeOut 1.4s;}
@keyframes fadeOut{0%{opacity: 100;}100%{opacity: 0;}}
`

Comment: that was my css code i couldn't paste my html code because its too long
its only include svg lines every line has an Id from my css code above

Comment: @NathanielFlick any help you can provide?

Comment: @MohammadSn edit your question and post your code there using the <> icon in the editor. Maybe this question will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57772415/repeat-multiple-css-animations/57772794