# How can I loop an svg text animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit

I found this very cool css on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/supah/pen/vXyBza). I'm very new to web animations and can't seem to find a way to reverse the animation (after completion of the animation). 
Essentially, I want the code to reiterate with the same animations but with a different text after the completion of the first text. How do I go about doing this?
I tried changing the `svg.intro.go .text-stroke` and tried adding/modifying the animation names, all in vain. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

you can put following styles in your respective animation class :

```
animation-iteration-count:infinite;
```

Original query on stackover flow : [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23458640/how-to-have-css3-animation-to-loop-forever)

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this and it seems to iterate it over and over. I want to change the text after iteration. How may I do this?