# How to Run Onclick Automatically in button

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to automatically run the onclick function in one button placed in phtml template.

This is the html file with the button code:

```
 <button type="button" id="review-btn" title="<?php echo $this->__('Place Order') ?>" class="button btn-checkout" onclick="review.save();"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Place Orderxxxxx') ?></span></span></button>
```

This is part of javascript file with save and review functions:

```
//review function starts 
var Review = Class.create();
Review.prototype = {
    initialize: function(form,saveUrl,successUrl,agreementsForm){
        this.form = form;
        this.saveUrl = saveUrl;
        this.successUrl = successUrl;

        this.agreementsForm = agreementsForm;
        this.onSave = this.nextStep.bindAsEventListener(this);
        this.onComplete = this.resetLoadWaiting.bindAsEventListener(this);
    },
      //function triggers when onloading on review save function
    loadingbox: function () {
         var translate = Translator.translate('processing').stripTags();
        $("review-please").update(' <div class="please-wait-loading">&nbsp;</div><span class="load-wait">'+translate+'</span>')
    var form = $('review-btn');
    form.disabled='true';

    },

    save: function(){
 var paymentmethod = payment.currentMethod;
        var validator = new Validation(this.form);
        if (validator.validate()) {


            var request = new Ajax.Request(
                this.saveUrl,
                {
                    method:'post',
                    parameters: Form.serialize(this.form),
                    onLoading:this.loadingbox.bind(this),
                    onComplete: this.onComplete,
                    onSuccess: function(transport)    {
                        if(transport.status == 200)    {
                            var data = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
                            if(!data.success)
                            {
                                alert(data.error_messages);
                                $("review-please").update('');
                                 $('review-btn').disabled='';

                            }
                            if (data.redirect) {
                                location.href = data.redirect;
                                return;
                            }
                            if(data.success){
                               //hostedpro and advanced payment action
                                if(paymentmethod == 'hosted_pro' || paymentmethod =='payflow_advanced')
                                {
                                        Element.hide('review-please');
                                        Element.hide('review-btn');
                                        document.getElementById('checkout-paypaliframe-load').style.display= 'block';
                                        iframedata = data.update_section["html"].replace("display:none","display:block");
                                        document.getElementById('checkout-paypaliframe-load').innerHTML = iframedata;

                                }
                                else   //other payment action
                                {
                                    this.isSuccess = true;
                                    window.location = data.success;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                onFailure: checkout.ajaxFailure.bind(checkout)
            }
            );
    //var updater = new Ajax.Updater('product-details', this.saveUrl, {method: 'post',parameters: Form.serialize(this.form)});
    }
},
```

If I simply change the onclick to setTimeout it doesn't work.

Comment: instead on calling onClick you can directly use setTimeout(review.save(),10000); use this it will call function after some interval
for more reference http://stackoverflow.com/a/11901175/4944490

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) in your javascript file.

Second parameter is time in milliseconds (1000ms = 1s), after which function will be executed.

```
setTimeout(review.save, 1000);
```

**EDIT:**

Sinde you use `this` in your function, you need to overwrite `this`. If called independently, scope isn't same anymore.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    review.save.apply(document.getElementById('review-btn'));
}, 1000);
```

**Full code**

Add this to last row of your JS file.

```
window.onload = function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        review.save.apply(document.getElementById('review-btn'));
    }, 1000);
};
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work. It will not save anything.

Comment: But it's calling function, right? I can't help you more, if you donät show more code. Saving is another topic.

Comment: I don't know if calling function works cause there is no change on page. Page use ajax above this button, maybe this is the reason.

Comment: Debug it then. Look in network tab, if AJAX gets called etc. Log wosmething to console etc. You really need to give me more information.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I will try to give you more information.

Comment: I've just updated the post with more information. thank you.

Comment: Edited my answer. Try again.

Comment: Thank you.Can you please paste the full code? I'm not a developer... thanks.

Comment: Add this full code to your JS file. Don't edit your `button`.