# calculate elapsed time javascript

Tags: javascript, time, difference

I want to change the background color of a page 5 seconds after the initial load. This is my code so far but it's not working:

```
var startDate = new Date();
var startTime = startDate.getTime();    


var nowDate = new Date();
var nowTime = nowDate.getTime();
var timeDifference = nowTime - startTime;

function difference() {
    if (timeDifference = 5000) {
        $("#body").css("background-color", "red");
    }
}
```

I would also like to write out the time difference, but it only works with `document.write()`.

Comment: remove Java and difference tags, they're not relevant to this question

Comment: I don't really see how you can expect this code to work. You don't even call `difference()` anywhere. In any case, @rbaghbanli has the correct solution.

Comment: I can't edit this... Ugh

Comment: @evolutionxbox Probably because someone has already made the same edits you want to and they are pending moderation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: Call a function after specific time period](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901074/javascript-call-a-function-after-specific-time-period)

Comment: @Chris yes. Yes it is

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's been modified and is now not a question

Comment: @eyemohini If you want to delete the question, there's a button at the bottom to do so.  No need to sabotage your post and create more work for us.

Comment: @IanMercer Woops, sorry to interrupt your thing there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the setTimeout function:

```
setTimeout(yourfunction, 5000);
```

Info: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp