# run function when scrolling up with wheel

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created a working zoom behavior in d3 v4 to examine a node graph, but am trying to implement two methods that are invoked by zooming.  When the user scrolls up with the mouse wheel to zoom in, I want that to invoke the method `undo()` and when the user scrolls down with the mouse wheel to zoom out, I want that to invoke the method `coarse()`.  I am struggling to figure out how to run two different methods depending on if the user scrolls up or down to zoom.  Below is how I wrote my basic zoom behavior.  Any help would be great, thanks!

```
  var zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, 2000])
  .on('zoom', zoomFn);

function zoomFn() {
  d3.select('#div2').select('svg').select('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + d3.event.transform.x + ',' + d3.event.transform.y + ') scale(' + d3.event.transform.k +')')


}
d3.select('#div2').select('svg').select('rect').call(zoom)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways you could go about implementing this. 
For a more event listener based approach I'd do the following:

```
var lastKnownPos = window.scrollY();
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    if (lastKnownPos > window.scrollY()) {
        //user is scrolling up, current position < last position
        undo();
    } else if () {
        //user is scrolling down, current position > last position
        coarse();
    }
    lastKnownPos = window.scrollY();
}
```

Essentially, the above snippet compares the previous stored value of the distance from the top of the page (given by `window.scrollY()`), to the current position on the page whenever the user scrolls. The difference in the values tells the snippet in which direction the user is scrolling.

A couple of notes:

-You should probably wrap this snippet in a block of code that it only triggers when the document is ready (so you don't make changes to the document before it is loaded, causing problems).

-If the user continuously scrolls, this function will be continuously called. If this is not a desired behavior, and you only want `undo()` and `coarse()` to be called once, you can set a boolean that gets checked before executing. Set the boolean to `false` once one of the functions is called, and is only set to true again after a timer (like `setTimeout()`) passes a desired period of time. You can read about some timing functions here: [Javascript: Call a function after specific time period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901074/javascript-call-a-function-after-specific-time-period).

Alternatively, if you don't want to/ can't use event listeners, you could use an entirely timer based approach. This would be a little harder to get to feel as smooth while also not slowing down your code. If you want me to elaborate on this please say so!