# How to open modal with javascript, after x seconds?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

My modal ID is #modal1 for example. 
Appears normally with a button function.

Comment: (q => http//google.it?q )( *js setInterval*, *js display html element*)

Comment: setTimeout( function(){ 
$('#modal1').modal('show');
  }  , 1000 );

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901074/javascript-call-a-function-after-specific-time-period ; http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-methods

Answer (score 2):

Check this out it might help you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBtn").click(function(){
        setTimeout( function(){ $('#modal1').modal('show'); } , 1000 );
    });
});
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
```